# Jquery - Add Image To Drop down items only

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to figure out how to simply add an arrow to my drop down menu items dynamically. The markup for my html is pretty simple. Just a

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> -Top level Link
            <ul>
                <li> -Child Level Links </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

What's inside them really isn't important to the issue, the structure I'd imagine is what is really needed..

What I am think I need to do is figure out which menu items have child level links and then either change the class of either parent link or the parent `<li>` to include the image of down arrow, or add the image of the down arrow via jquery.

Any help in at least figuring out the right method of doing this would be appreciated, even if you don't share code I can always use google to figure out the way.

I think I have this figured out for my needs.. More or less....

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('.hmenu').has('ul').addClass('arrow'); 
       $('ul.arrow').find('a:first').append('*'); });
```

I know I can append html and create a div and and place an image inside the div and with a little css make sure sure looks okay.

If anyone has an easier way to do this I would greatly like to know. I haven't had much need or a chance to do java script/jquery as I'm usually staring at php code, but I like dynamic so the code knows what to do when it encounters x.

Thanks to all who replied!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$("nav > ul > li > ul").parent().addClass("arrow");
```

Comment: After testing the code I had I figured out I was wrong... This allowed me to add the class I needed! Thank you much for this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use descendent selectors for this to add the class to the relevant items ex:

```
$('ul li ul li').addClass('child');
```

See also for more info:

http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

Comment: Here is what I came up with while tooling around with this for a while. I very rarely do any kind of java script/jquery but I'm thinking this will work.

   

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hmenu').has('ul').addClass('arrow');
    $('ul.arrow').find('a:first').append('*');
    });

I have some testing still to do but this should work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple arrow is can be done via css only, "**∨**" is a down arrow in ascii code..

The css:-

```
.arrow1 { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; }
```

Add this line after first li:-

```
<li>-<span class="arrow1">&or;</span>Top level Link
          <ul>
              <li> -Child Level Links
           </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: He says he needs to be able to add the class dynamically so it will require js/jquery to add the class.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use a jquery plugin which already does that..

here is a list of all the plugins you can experiment with..

[Differenet dropdown plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/)